# ADFS 2016 - ApplicationGroup - single native app - multiple web api endpoints

Tags: asp.net-web-api, adfs, windows-server-2016

I'd like to validate the following scenario:
ADFS (win2016) is acting as an **Identity Provider** in a setup where

a single mobile app is consuming 2 api's

1. api.contoso.be
2. otherresource.contoso.be

These three applications are grouped together in a **ADFS Application Group**:

- mobile app as a "**Native application**"
- api.contoso.be and otherresource.contoso.be as "**Web API**" **applications**

The mobile app gets an access token when authenticating succesfully against ADFS.
The access token is provided with een aud-claim for "api.contoso.be".

**Problem**: I'm currently unable to reuse that same access token to access the second api "otherresource.contoso.be".

**Question**: at this point I'm not 100% sure that ADFS ApplicationGroups are meant to support such a scenario.

If so, I'm probably overlooking something in the ADFS-configuration.
If not, what's a better ADFS setup to support this scenario?

Comment: Can you include the code you are using in the client to sign in and request the token? Are you specifying the resource (API) in the token request?